# natbib package - authoryear problems

Tags: natbib

I am using the `natbib` package with the `\citep` command. I want to have `author-year citations[author, year]` but when I compile everything is in the `numerical [29]` format. I tried everything, including the following command:

```
\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}
```

and

```
\RequirePackage[authoryear, sort&compress]{natbib}

\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}
```

It does not work... I have verified the code and I am certain that I don't use the `biblatex` or any other citation package. I am using sharelatex.com.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! `does not work` is not really helpful. Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: In particular, you need to state which document class and which bibliography style you use.

Comment: Document class is the following: \documentclass[12pt,oneside,letterpaper]{book} . I am using plainat as the following: \bibliographystyle{plainnat}. 

However I cannot copy the entire code here because I am using a .sty file that is over 600 lines long (obviously not written by me). I verified in it and there's nothing that should override the \usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}. What I mean by its does not work is that every citations appear as numbering like [29], [3, p.15], etc.

Comment: Do you get any bibliography-related error or warning messages (check the log and blg files)? Did you try deleting the aux and bbl files and recompiling from scratch (latex, bibtex, and latex twice more)? Are there any `\setbibliographystyle` or `\bibpunct` directives (which may well override the `authoryear` option)? Do you load a template from an external file (which may contain instructions that override the `authoryear` option)?

Comment: HAHA! I had the following command: \bibpunct{[}{]}{,}{n}{,}{,~} hidden in the .sty file. I just removed it and everything works well! Many thanks @Mico.

Comment: Good to know that one of my hunches was correct. :-) If you need square brackets rather than round parentheses for the citation call-outs, you could re-instate the `\bibpunct` directive -- but with the fourth argument set to `a`, obviously -- or you could provide the option `square` when loading the `natbib` package.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is solved by comments